# Как сделать капчу повторяющейся два раза?

Tags: php, html, случайные-числа

Имею текстовую капчу, и проблема в том что когда заходишь в регистрацию, то появляется вопрос, он генерируется из случайного списка, а вводишь ответ на него и уже нажимаешь на кнопку, как пишет что он не правильный, ведь по повторному обращению к скрипту он уже другой, и если просто кликать по кнопке есть шанс что снова попадётся тот вопрос, и регистрация завершиться, но это не нужно. Есть идея: сделать повтор рандома, заходишь на сайт, выводится вопрос, вводишь, нажимаешь и в повторном обращении он все тотже. Вот мой код, может что-то придумать можно:

```
$quotes           = array(
    'Какая самая популярная карта в CS:GO?',
    'Сколько времени дается на покупку предметов? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько секунд длится дефьюз без набора сапёра? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько секунд длится дефьюз с набором сапёра? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько раундов длится матчмейкинг? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько всего игроков в матчмейкинге? (ответ цифрами)',
    'На какой карте зоны закладки находятся на друг друге?',
    'На какой карте есть ковры?',
    'На какой карте есть зига или шорт?',
    'Какое оригинальное название петуха?'
);
$random_number    = rand(1, 10);
$secret           = $quotes[$random_number];
if ($random_number == 1) {
    $otvet = 'de_dust2';
}
if ($random_number == 2) {
    $otvet = '20';
}
if ($random_number == 3) {
    $otvet = '10';
}
if ($random_number == 4) {
    $otvet = '5';
}
if ($random_number == 5) {
    $otvet = '30';
}
if ($random_number == 6) {
    $otvet = '10';
}
if ($random_number == 7) {
    $otvet = 'de_nuke';
}
if ($random_number == 8) {
    $otvet = 'de_mirage';
}
if ($random_number == 9) {
    $otvet = 'de_dust2';
}
if ($random_number == 10) {
    $otvet = 'P90';
}
if ($eng == 'reg') {
    echo "
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='title'>Регистрация пользователя</div>
    <div id='box-news'>
    <center>
    <input class='input' type='text' style='width: 85%;' name='login' id='one' placeholder='Логин:'/><br>
    <input class='input' type='password' style='width: 85%;' id='two' name='password' placeholder='Пароль:'/><br>
    <input class='input' type='text' style='width: 85%;' id='three' name='secret' placeholder='$secret'/><br>
    <input value='YES' type='checkbox' id='five'  name='rule'/>Согласны ли вы с <a onclick='rules()' href='#'>правилами</a>?<br>
    <input class='btn' id='reg' type='button' onclick='register()' value='Зарегистрироваться'/><br>
    При регистрации недопустимы русские буквы, и некоторые символы.<br>
    Также ваш пароль и логин не должны быть меньше 6 символов.<br>
    </center>
    </div>
    </div>
    ";
    $main = 12;
}
```

Все выполняется в одном скрипте.

Comment: запоминайте правильный ответ в сесии или зашифрованной куке. Тогда при получении ответа нужно будет просто сверить.

А делать функцию, которая будет дважды отдавать одно и тоже - плохая идея - представьте, что у вас регистрируется два человека одновременно.

Comment: попробую с куками пока

Comment: только не храните явно, хотя бы добавляйте какую то соль.

Comment: А соль то зачем кукам?

Comment: потому что любой человек откроет в браузере консоль, увидит как оно в куках сохраняется и быстро напишет бота:)

Comment: ну тут по рандому то всего 10 вопросов, по любому бота могут написать. У меня другое: я буду одну регу на один айпи делать.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользовался куками.

```html
$quotes           = array(
    'Какая самая популярная карта в CS:GO?',
    'Сколько времени дается на покупку предметов? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько секунд длится дефьюз без набора сапёра? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько секунд длится дефьюз с набором сапёра? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько раундов длится матчмейкинг? (ответ цифрами)',
    'Сколько всего игроков в матчмейкинге? (ответ цифрами)',
    'На какой карте зоны закладки находятся на друг друге?',
    'На какой карте есть ковры?',
    'На какой карте есть зига или шорт?',
    'Какое оригинальное название петуха?'
);
$random_number    = rand(0, 9);
if (empty($vopr))
{
setcookie("random", $random_number, time()+120);
}
$secret           = $quotes[$vopr];
if ($vopr == 0) {
    $otvet = 'de_dust2';
}
if ($vopr == 1) {
    $otvet = '20';
}
if ($vopr == 2) {
    $otvet = '10';
}
if ($vopr == 3) {
    $otvet = '5';
}
if ($vopr == 4) {
    $otvet = '30';
}
if ($vopr == 5) {
    $otvet = '10';
}
if ($vopr == 6) {
    $otvet = 'de_nuke';
}
if ($vopr == 7) {
    $otvet = 'de_mirage';
}
if ($vopr == 8) {
    $otvet = 'de_dust2';
}
if ($vopr == 9) {
    $otvet = 'P90';
}
```